# How to merge two subs with Private Sub Worksheet_Change on sheet, which have different triggers

Tags: excel, subroutine, vba

I have tried a lot of variations for this ( all found online, since I am a novice on this) and cant' get it to work. Where am I going wrong?

I have a spreadsheet with 2 cells that can be changed with drop down, for each cell I need a different sub to activate on change. I can make each of these work individually, but not on combining them.

Can you help, please?

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'hides currencies that aren't required

'On Error GoTo 99
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B8")) Is Nothing Then
Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Range("B8").Text = "" Then
Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
GoTo Letscontinue
Else

Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
GoTo Letscontinue
End If: End If
Exit Sub

'adds new lines for addenda during contract live cycle
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B168")) Is Nothing Then

If Range("B168").Text = "Yes" Then
Range("B172").Select
If Range("B172").Text = "Yes" Then
Range("B176").Select
If Range("B176").Text = "Yes" Then
Range("B180").Select
If Range("B176").Text = "Yes" Then
Else
ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).Rows("1:4").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
ActiveCell.Offset(3, 1).Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-4]C+1"
Selection.ClearContents
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "No"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
GoTo Letscontinue
End If: End If: End If: End If: End If

Exit Sub

Letscontinue:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub

99:
Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A general template could resemble:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B8")) Is Nothing Then
            '
            '   your code
            '
        End If
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B168")) Is Nothing Then
            '
            '   your code
            '
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is failing is because you have an `Exit Sub` statement outside your first If block

```
GoTo Letscontinue
End If: End If
Exit Sub   <----- Remove this
```

This `Exit Sub` statement will always be hit as it is outside of the If block, so this line of code

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B168")) Is Nothing Then ....
```

will **never** be reached.

---

You should remove the `Exit Sub` at the bottom of your code as well. As this will mean that the `Application.EnableEvents` will not be hit.

```
Exit Sub  <---- Remove this

Letscontinue:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
```